# Three.js gltf load doesn't update outside variable

Tags: javascript, three.js, gltf

After importing gltf object it doesn't assign it to outside variable. Model appears in browser but I can't access it.

```
let model;
gltfLoader.load('./assets/javaLogo.gltf', function(gltf){
    model = gltf.scene;
    model.scale.set(44,44,44);
    scene.add(model);
    model.position.x = 44;
    model.position.y = -12;
});
console.log(model);// undefined
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The console.log gets executed immediately after you start to load the model at that time it has not finished loading. You can test this by having a console.log inside the callback function. (It will be executed after the one which logs undefined)

If you wanna access the model right after loading, you can do that inside the callback function. If you want to access it for example in an event listener you can still do that, but you have to make sure model isn't undefined anymore before that.

Comment: Thanks. Also how would you return the object with function when it is loaded? For example I have a function with which I import the object. When I call the said function, I want it to return the imported object ,but somehow I need to wait for it to load first before returning.